# iterating numpy matrix and getting all values with score gt than

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a company list(cmp_list) where I am comparing each of the values with another one using some custom algorithm and have come up with this matrix(Score Matrix) of all the scores. if you read thru the matrix you will see row1 and col1 is 1 bcoz the first item is cmp_list is matched with itself and similarly row3 and col3 is 1. Now row1,col3 is 0 bcoz first item in cmp-list is matched with the third item in cmp_list i.e. matching walmart and home depot so obviously score is 0.

I want to get the list of all items in cmp_list whose score is > 0.5

```
cmp_list =    ['Walmart', 'Walmart super', 'Home Depot', 'Sears', 'Home Depot Center', 'Home Depot']
```

**Score Matrix:**

```
[[1.         1.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [1.         1.         0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         1.         0.         0.66666667 0.81649658]
 [0.         0.         0.         1.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.66666667 0.         1.         0.81649658]
 [0.         0.         0.81649658 0.         0.81649658 1.        ]]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
cmp_list_1 = ['Walmart', 'Walmart super']
cmp_list_2 = ['Home Depot', 'Home Depot Center', 'Home Depot']
```

I have tried doing this using nested for loop but I am looking for something more Pythonic and concise to achieve this:

**My code so far:**

```
if(np.count_nonzero(score_matrix - np.diag(np.diagonal(score_matrix)))) > 0:
                rowsi, cols = np.nonzero(score_matrix)
                for it in zip(rowsi,cols):
                        if np.where(score_matrix[it[0]][it[1]] >= 0.5):
```

Comment: How are you getting cmp_list_1  and cmp_list_2 from the posted code?

Comment: @min2bro, According to your explanation of Score Matrix, the values in Score Matrix can only be 0's and 1's, with all the 1's present on the diagonal. But how are you showing values like 0.66666667?

Comment: @fountainhead, All the ones are present on diagonal because that is comparison of the same element, so row, cols are same at diagonal. No i just gave example on how the comparison works but it can be anything between 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np


a = score_matrix
a[np.diag_indices_from(a)] = 0
set([tuple(sorted(np.array(cmp_list)[(np.c_[[i],np.where(j>0.5)])][0]))for i,j in enumerate(a) if any(j>0.5)])

{('Home Depot', 'Home Depot', 'Home Depot Center'),
 ('Walmart', 'Walmart super')}
```

A different way:

```
def relation(x,dat):
    k = sorted(np.unique(np.r_[dat[1][np.in1d(dat[0],x)],x,dat[0][np.in1d(dat[1],x)]]))
    if k==x: return k
    else: return relation(k,dat)

def rel(a,cmp_list):
    a[np.diag_indices_from(a)] = 0
    mat = np.where(a>0.5)
    ind = list(np.unique(mat[0]))
    w = []
    while ind:
        k = relation([ind[0]],mat)
        w.append(list(np.array(cmp_list)[k]))
        if any(np.in1d(ind,k)):
            ind = list(np.array(ind)[~np.in1d(ind,k)])
        if len(ind)>0:
            del ind[0]
    return w

rel(score_matrix,cmp_list)
[['Walmart', 'Walmart super'],
 ['Home Depot', 'Home Depot Center', 'Home Depot']]
```

Comment: what's cmp_list here in rel(a,cmp_list)?

Comment: its what you wrote: `cmp_list =    ['Walmart', 'Walmart super', 'Home Depot', 'Sears', 'Home Depot Center', 'Home Depot']`  a is the score matrix